# Does reflection preserve wavelength?

Tags: optics, photons, reflection, wavelength

If a photon at a certain wavelength gets reflected on a surface, does the reflected photon have *exactly* the same wavelength? If not, what is the distribution of its wavelength?

I know about up- and downconversion, but I don't know how frequent it is. And is it the only mechanism that changes the wavelength of "reflected" light?

Comment: P.S.: If there is a problem with my question, please let me know in a comment, and give me a chance to improve it, rather than simply downvoting or closing it.

Answer (score 3):

First, there reflection is basically elastic scattering. In elastic scattering, the energy and phase of the photons is kept, but they change angle.

There are two types of reflection:

1. diffuse, where the angle of reflection is random, and does not have anything to do with the angle of incidence
2. specular, this is what you see in metals, mirrors, where the angle of reflection is equal to the angle of incidence, and, the relative angle of the photons is kept, that is how a mirror image is built

Now in both cases, reflection, that is elastic scattering, keeps the energy (frequency and wavelength) of the photons.

You are asking if the energy is exactly the same. Now only if it is a perfect mirror. But there are no perfect mirrors, so the energy of the photon will always change a little bit, but in this case of a mirror, the change is negligible. The main point is that the relative energy, wavelength and phase of the photons is kept and that is how a mirror image is built in the case of specular reflection. In the case of diffuse reflection, the energy level is the same too, but since this does not build a mirror image, there is not sense in requiring the energy levels to be the same.

You are asking whether only up and downconversion can change the wavelength of the "reflected" light. Now this is a common misconception. You are thinking about reflection as absorption and re-emission. This is not correct.

When a photon interacts with an atom three things can happen:

1. elastic scattering, reflection, when the photon keeps its energy and changes angle
2. inelastic scattering, when the photon gives part of its energy to the atom and changes angle
3. absorption, when the photon gives all its energy to the atom and the absorbing electron moves to a higher energy level as per QM

Now reflection does not change the wavelength. Absorption and re-emission does. It can happen by:

1. up and downconversion
2. two photon absorption
3. second harmonic generation

So basically you have to understand that when you talk about reflection, that is elastic scattering. All three things happen with a material when light shines on them, elastic scattering, inelastic scattering, and absorption and re-emission. The ratio of them is different for different materials. For metals, it is elastic scattering. For a simple white wall, it is more absorption and re-emission.

Comment: How do you know I'm "thinking about reflection as absorption and re-emission"?

Comment: I'm using the word "reflection" as a general term to mean any light that is coming from an object as a consequence of it being illuminated.

Answer (score 1):

The frequency does not change generally. The only case would be if the reflecting medium is moving, where a Doppler shift would be introduced.

Comment: Why doesn't it change? According to what theory? Described by which formulas? Without supporting details, this post sounds like a personal opinion rather than a scientific answer.

Comment: @safesphere Principle of conservation of energy. What changes upon reflection is the phase, ampitude of wave and direction generally, this does not imply a change in wavelength. Easier for me to answer would be if you said why you think it SHOULD change and i'll adress your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, it can be easier to think about frequencies than wavelengths.

As the signal arrives at the reflector, it has a particular frequency.  From the point of view of the mirror, the incoming and outgoing frequencies must be identical.  If the frequencies were different, then that would imply that the reflector was either creating or erasing wave peaks (or that they were somehow "building up" at the point of reflection).

Given the input and output frequencies are identical in that frame we can calculate how the frequencies change as the signal is observed in other frames.

Assume we have a source producing $f_0$ and a reflector receding from the source with velocity $v$ (where $v \ll c$).  Then the reflector observes a frequency:
$$f_m = \left(\frac{1}{1 + \frac{v}{c}} \right) f_0$$

In the frame of the reflector, the reflected frequency is identical.  But in the frame of the source, that frequency will be seen as:

$$f_r = \left( \frac{1}{1 + \frac{v}{c}}\right)f_m$$ or
$$f_r = \left( \frac{1}{1 + \frac{v}{c}} \right)^2f_0$$

In the case where the source and the reflector are at rest, $v = 0$ and the equation reduces to $f_r = f_0$.  For waves, $c = \lambda f$ or $\lambda = \frac{c}{f}$.  Since $c$ and $f$ are both constant for the inbound and outbound waves, the wavelength must also be constant.

If the mirror were moving away from the source, the fraction is less than 1 and the observed frequency of the reflected light would be less than the original frequency.  Given the inverse relationship with frequency and wavelength,  the observed wavelength of the reflected wave would be greater.